# JavaScript - How to load images

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Just wondering how I would load an image using JS like this:

*Maps.js*

```
{id: 21, colour: 'res/pillar.png', solid: 1, bounce: 
0.30}, /*Loading the image in as an attribute*/
```

*Engine.js*

```
/*From draw_tile function*/

if (!tile || !tile.colour) return;
debugger;
context.drawImage(tile.colour, x, y);
context.fillRect(
    x,
    y,
    this.tile_size,
    this.tile_size
);

-----------------------------------

/*From draw_map function*/

this.draw_tile(t_x, t_y, this.current_map.data[y][x], context);
```

Console:

```
tile.colour
"res/pillar.png"
```

Attribute is working.

But get this error on - context.drawImage()

```
Engine.js:173 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
at Engine.draw_tile (Engine.js:173)
at Engine.draw_map (Engine.js:199)
at Engine.draw (Engine.js:450)
at Loop (index.html:87)
at index.html:94
```

I'm probably poorly going about this or that I am just missing something, but how do I load the image in the way I am coding? I also believe I may need an onload() but where?

Andy

Comment: is the path to your image correct?

Answer (score 0):

> The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement
>   or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or
>   ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

The error is telling you that `drawImage` expects an Image (or a few other options) - not a string:

```
var imgTile = new Image();
imgTile.src = tile.colour;
imgTile.onload = function() {
   context.drawImage(imgTile, x, y)
}
```

Comment: ok so in that respect, would colour: 'var imgTile = new Image();
imgTile.src = tile.colour;' work?

Comment: Sorry, you need to wait for onload - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It just by passes the drawImage. Post below.

Comment: Console output for Context: 

    onload:null
    onloadeddata:null
    onloadedmetadata:null
    onloadstart:null

also 

    fillStyle:"#333333"

and there the drawImage attribute would not be in the list.

Comment: Are you seeing the image load in the console? At this point it seems like an incorrect path

Comment: console output: imgTile.src = tile.colour
"res/pillar.png"
context.drawImage(imgTile, x, y)
undefined

Comment: folder layout: Game_name/res, Game_name/scripts, Game_name/index.html. All images are under Game_name/res/... aka Game_name/res/pillar.png